# How to validate that a deep link url goes to a real page?

Tags: android, ios, http, web, deep-linking

While working on a project I have a series of deep links that go to different apps (could be iOS or android). I want to validate that these urls actually go somewhere and won't result in an error. I've looked everywhere an haven't found any clear solutions.

For example the deep link
`'instagram://user?username=espn'`

will open up the @espn account directly in the instagram app, but

`'instagram://abcd'` will not do anything and should be invalid.

- NOTE: this question is NOT involving the syntax or regex for deep links. Rather, I want to know how I would go about validating the deep links go somewhere (ex. for a regular url I can check that the http status code isn't 404).

Comment: seems like this would be impossible, as everything after the protocol is parsed by the individual app?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure you can as a 'deep link' is the equivalent of a third-party API. At best you can use the test track with the third-party production apps to see if they behave as expected but otherwise third-party apps are free to change.

Comment: i think its impossible. You can only check if, in this scenario, Instagram was installed in your device or not by using `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL`.  Everything else is how the target app parses the parameters

Comment: Do you need an automated solution?  You could test each link by hand.